# Open Store App in Wpf current window using IApplicationActivationManager using C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using `IApplicationActivationManager` Interface method to start my WinStore package. But desired application is opening in separate window. I need this app to open in current window. Could you please help me for the same. My code is following:

```
[ComImport, Guid("45BA127D-10A8-46EA-8AB7-56EA9078943C")]
class ApplicationActivationManager { }

static class MetroLauncher
{
    public static uint LaunchApp(string packageFullName, string arguments = null)
    {
        IntPtr pir = IntPtr.Zero;
        try
        {
            int error = OpenPackageInfoByFullName(packageFullName, 0, out pir);
            Debug.Assert(error == 0);
            if (error != 0)
                throw new Win32Exception(error);

            int length = 0, count;
            GetPackageApplicationIds(pir, ref length, null, out count);

            var buffer = new byte[length];
            error = GetPackageApplicationIds(pir, ref length, buffer, out count);
            Debug.Assert(error == 0);
            if (error != 0)
                throw new Win32Exception(error);

            var appUserModelId = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, IntPtr.Size * count, length - IntPtr.Size * count);

            var activation = (IApplicationActivationManager)new ApplicationActivationManager();
            uint pid;
            int hr = activation.ActivateApplication(appUserModelId, arguments ?? string.Empty, ActivateOptions.NoErrorUI, out pid);

            if (hr < 0)
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
            return pid;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (pir != IntPtr.Zero)
                ClosePackageInfo(pir);
        }

    }

    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    static extern int OpenPackageInfoByFullName([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string fullName, uint reserved, out IntPtr packageInfo);

    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    static extern int GetPackageApplicationIds(IntPtr pir, ref int bufferLength, byte[] buffer, out int count);

    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    static extern int ClosePackageInfo(IntPtr pir);
}




[ComImport, InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), Guid("2e941141-7f97-4756-ba1d-9decde894a3d")]
interface IApplicationActivationManager {
    int ActivateApplication([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string appUserModelId, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string arguments, 
        ActivateOptions options, out uint processId);
    int ActivateForFile([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string appUserModelId, IntPtr pShelItemArray, 
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string verb, out uint processId);
    int ActivateForProtocol([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string appUserModelId, IntPtr pShelItemArray, 
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string verb, out uint processId);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "current window" ?

Comment: means installed Windows Store app on given pc will be loaded in WPF application grid control. we will just provide package name for that application.For Example:                                                                         LaunchApp(string packageFullName, string arguments = null)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this in not possible